# Is it possible to create a static library C++ with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I had a C/C++ Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition project that was defined to generate a DLL, and I'm having a lot of misery with "undefined symbols" which I wanted to use in another project, so I decided to see what it would give if I changed the project settings so that it would generate a static library instead.

So in the Properties window of the project I went to

Configuration Properties > General > Project Defaults > Configuration Type

and set the Configuration Type to **Static Library** 
The target extension is **.lib**.

When I do a rebuild I *still* get a fresh dll file in my Release folder, as well as a lib, and the DLL file is much bigger than the lib file. This makes the lib file look like an "export lib" file and it looks like nothing has changed.
This still happens if I stop and restart Visual Studio.

Am I missing something or does this look like a bug to you?

Answer (score 1):

In `Configuration Properties - C/C++ - Runtime Library` change setting to **`Multi-threaded (/MT)`** for `Release` configuration and to **`Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`** for `Debug` configuration.

[image: Screenshot of Settings]

Also, check `Configuration Properties - General - General - Target extension` is set to **`.lib`**.

Check settings for all configurations (`Release` and `Debug` if you use them).

Answer (score 0):

Why have you changed your project type? If you need DLL, build DLL. Post exact errors received during DLL compilation. Perhaps you missed some `dllexport`/`dllimport` declspecs.

Regarding `.lib`: are you sure, that DLL is generated during build? Perhaps it is the output from previous (DLL) configuration? Have you tried to compile test app using this `.lib`? Perhaps it is valid and compiled properly?

Another matter: have you removed all dclspecs from function signatures after project type change? When building static library, none of them are applicable.

Comment: I dont really "need" a DLL. There are no build errors, but some warnings. The time of the DLL was always the latest time. I used the preprocessor to remove the dlspecs since they were #defined by a macro to make it easy to change. There seems to be genuine Microsoft bug that it cant forget the previous setting.

Comment: However a bit of fiddling with the Configuration: Debug vs Release seems to have worked around the bug.

Comment: So it is not a bug. It's simply an invalid configuration. Have you checked all things I mentioned?

Comment: Yes I checked everything you mentionned, it's the first things that came to mind. Amazingly the last output line indicated it was generating a dll. Unfortunately I dont have a recorder that recorded all my steps. Now that I have a regular lib, I still get the same undefined symbols, so I am dropping this attempt and reverting to the DLL config.

Comment: Did you add reference to this `.lib` to your project?

Comment: You have raised a good point though, that I may have had an invalid configuration.